# iterate and condition in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
shipportMD=pd.read_csv('shipportMD.csv')

for importName in shipportMD['importName'].unique():
    if (len(shipportMD['ItemDecision']=='Accepted')>len(shipportMD['ItemDecision']=='Rejected')):
        print (shipportMD['importName'])
```

I need to print `importName` values where there are more `'Accepted'` values than `'Rejected'` for `ItemDecision`.

So, for example:

**importName** : x,y,x,x

**ItemDecision** : Rejected,Accepted,Rejected,Accepted.

So `x` has 2 Rejected and one Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and then a Boolean mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'Decision': ['Accepted', 'Rejected', 'Rejected', 'Rejected',
                                'Accepted', 'Accepted', 'Rejected', 'Accepted']})

df_ct = pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Decision'])

condition = df_ct['Accepted'] > df_ct['Rejected']

res = df_ct[condition].index  
# Int64Index([2], dtype='int64', name='ID')
```

Or perform a calculation of your choice on the cross-tabulated results:

```
print(df_ct)

Decision  Accepted  Rejected
ID                          
1                1         3
2                3         1
```